# C++ Sorting objects based on two data members

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I understand you can insert a user-defined class in to a `std::vector` and then overload the sorting mechanism so that it compares on a particular data member. However, how would you sort a `std::vector<MyClass>` where `MyClass` has two data members and you want to add a "second level" of sorting on the second data member? So sort on data member `a` and where `a` is equal, then sort on data member `b`?

Comment: Overloading the sorting mechanism allows you to execute arbitrary code on two objects being compared. You should be able to add as many "levels" as you want.

Comment: Just like you'd do it for a comparison on a single member. I suggest learning how to do that first (there are multiple questions about this on SO), then simply modifying the functor you wrote to compare on the second member if the first is equal.

Answer (score 9):

Create a custom comparator using [*`std::tuple`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
    #include <tuple>
   //..    
    struct comp
    {
      bool operator()(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) const
      {
        return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b);
      }
    };
```

It will use `a` first and then `b` second